# How to run Python code periodically that connects to the internet

Tags: python, cloud

I'm working on a Python script that connects to the Twitter API to pull in some tweets into an array, then pushes this to a mysql database. It's a pretty basic script, but I'd like to set it up to run weekly.

I'd like to know the best way to deploy it so that it can automatically run weekly, so that I don't have to manually run it every week.

Comment: Your question isn't really about Python programming — its' more generic — so is off-topic here on SO.

Comment: which is your SO ? linux you can use crontab and at windows task scheduler

Comment: The [`sched`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html#module-sched) module might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on platform where you intend to run your python code. As martin says, this is not a python question and more of scheduling related question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a batch file that can activate python and run your script and then, use task scheduler to schedule youe batch file execution weekly